# Observe Changes With Change Tracking / SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've enabled Change Tracking in my SQL Server 2012 database:

```
ALTER DATABASE SEMESS 
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE SEMESS.QRQC.Vorgang 
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON);
```

Afterwards, I created a stored procedure which is intended to return the last modifications on this table by containing this

```
DECLARE @next_baseline bigint;  
SET @next_baseline = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();
```

It's not working. My goal is to return the highest/latest version number row.

Any hints or tricks are kindly requested.

BTW: this is working but returning all changes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QRQC.WatchVorgangChanges
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES QRQC.Vorgang, 0) AS CT;
END
```

Comment: You don't use change tracking in your code at all. Change tracking doesn't use dates nor does it add modification columns to tables. There's a version, not timestamp, value that's the entire database's change version.  Did you check [the change tracking documentation and examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#use-the-change-tracking-functions-to-obtain-changes)? You get modified PK values since the last version with `CHANGETABLE(CHANGES myTable, @last_synchronization_version)`

Comment: Yes I do, since the (working) procedure is returning the (version) changes in my table "Vorgang"

Comment: No you don't. There's no call to `CHANGETABLE(CHANGES mytable, @last_synchronization_version)` anywhere, only filtering using your own `last_modified` field

Comment: can you elaborate? Which changes should I make?

Comment: Have you actually read the docs for it? The idea is that there's something that keeps track of changes, every change increments a specific number, you can call it change tracking iD. This number is passed to the CHANGETABLE function to get the changes since this number. For this reason, you need to store the last number somewhere, and every time you fetch changes, you have to increment it, so you don't get the same changes twice. You can read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336282/sql-server-change-tracking-see-only-the-last-updated-columns-on-the-row/76351762#76351762

Comment: Did you *read the documentation*? Did you follow the link I posted? It links directly to the query examples

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to store the last version change in a separate table for further reference. Here is my personal solution for retrieving the last change in the Vorgang Table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QRQC.WatchVorgangChanges
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @max_version BIGINT;
        
    -- Retrieve
    SELECT @max_version = ISNULL(MAX(SYS_CHANGE_VERSION - 1), 0)
    FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES QRQC.Vorgang, 0) AS CT;
    
    -- Insert Into separate Table for further reference, delete all stuff first
    DELETE FROM QRQC.LastChangeVersionTable;
    INSERT INTO QRQC.LastChangeVersionTable(Version)
    VALUES (@max_version);
    -- Print last version
    SELECT @max_version AS LastVersion;
    
    -- Print Changetable
    SELECT *
    FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES QRQC.Vorgang, @max_version) AS CT;
END
```